# Is the In App Purchase server model device-oriented or user-oriented?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am working with In App Purchase with server model. All documents describe In Ap purchase is device oriented means register user can not use other device for extend his subscription..so is it true?

Answer (score 0):

It is binded to itunes account in which user downloaded that app, If the user wants to use the subscription in different device he needs to download the app in that device with same iTune account.
Or
You have to maintain the info(Purchased info etc) with respect to user(unique id) in the server and you need to provide related data when user login(unique id) to the app in different device.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can use in-app purchase to extend a subscription on devices other than the one the purchase is made on.  In fact, for certain types of in-app purchasing (non-consumables), it's a requirement that the purchased content be made available on all the user's devices.

The key to understand is that how the purchase is fulfilled (that is, the content delivery) is entirely up to you.  In-App purchasing simply provides a mechanism for purchasing and validating the receipt.  You can re-request all receipts for purchases a user has made on any device the user logs into, and it's up to your app to insure that the content is unlocked or delivered based on those receipts.